# kmeans cluster number does not match with k value

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scipy, k-means

code based on [this article](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-colors-image-clustering-python/) works as expected when I define only 3 clusters. But when I change the number of clusters, I do not get the equal number of clusters back.

```
from matplotlib import image as img
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

image = img.imread("my_logo1.jpg")
image.shape

r = []
g = []
b = []

for line in image:
    for pixel in line:
        temp_r, temp_g, temp_b = pixel
        r.append(temp_r / 255)
        g.append(temp_g / 255)
        b.append(temp_b / 255)

df = pd.DataFrame({"red": r, "green": g, "blue": b})

from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans
cluster_centers, distortion = kmeans(df[["red", "green", "blue"]], 7)

print(cluster_centers)
```

> cluster centers returned are only 3, expected 7

I expected the same number of colors to return back as defined in the kmeans function.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: # Python 3.7.1 # scipy 1.2.1

Comment: When I select a colorful image, it works as expected. But when I select a simple image with only 1 or 2 colors (for e.g. google logo), kmeans is not able to create more than 3/4 clusters. Sounds logical but needs confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading source code for [`kmeans()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/cluster/vq.py#L319) function, you can note the use of a supporting function [`_kmeans()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/cluster/vq.py#L270), where you can find:

```
code_book = code_book[has_members]
```

[`has_members`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx#L325) is a boolean array indicating which clusters have members, resulting from [`_vq.update_cluster_means()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/_vq.pyx#L306).

In short, when you specify the number of clusters `k`, the algorithm returns a set of centroids (**at most** `k`) with the lowest distortion seen. Empty clusters are simply removed during the update-step of K-means.